# detect first change

Tags: sqlite

A table saves the status of a variable V1 every day:

```
V1 Status Date
-----------------
X  A      date_1
Y  C      date_2
X  B      date_3
X  B      date_4
Y  D      date_5
X  B      date_6
Y  D      date_7
X  A      date_8
```

I am interested in: When does the variable change its status, and what is the new status?

The result should be:

```
V1 Status Date
-----------------
X  A      date_1
X  B      date_3
X  A      date_8
Y  C      date_2
Y  D      date_5
```

Comment: And your research has turned up what so far ...? https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+detect+column+value+change+between+rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to show those rows that have a value different from the previous one:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE Status IS NOT (SELECT Status
                     FROM MyTable AS T2
                     WHERE T2.V1 = MyTable.V1
                       AND T2.Date < MyTable.Date
                     ORDER BY T2.Date DESC
                     LIMIT 1);
```